# How to count item values from dictionary in python using keyword

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in a below format:

```
folders = {'Master folder': ['Training'], 'Child folder': ['Training videos', 'Training documents', 'Training workouts', 'Training practicals']}
```

I want to count the values as below is expected,

```
count_of_masterfolder = 1
count_of_childfolder = 4
```

So far I did this,

```
    co_master = folders.items['Master folder']
    co_child = folders.items['Child folder']
    print(co_master, co_child)
```

Am getting this error:

```
    co = folders.items['Master folder']
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

What should I do?

Comment: That's not how you index a dictionary - just use `folders[key]`. `items` is a function that returns a view object / list of all key-value pairs in the dictionary.

Comment: this doesnt returns me my value, as I said in expected section, I need to store each count values in separate variables and print

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want `count_of_masterfolder = 1` etc. as the *output* of your program, or do you want the count be assigned to variables?

In the former case, you can use something like this:

```
for key, value in folder.items():
    print ("count of", key, "=", len(value))
```

In the latter case, the following will work for your particular case:

```
count_of_masterfolder = len(folder["Master folder"])
count_of_childfolder = len(folder["Child folder"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **dict** comprehension:

```
{k: len(v) for k,v in folders.items()}
```

Full example:

```
folders = {'Master folder': ['Training'], 'Child folder': [
    'Training videos', 'Training documents', 'Training workouts', 'Training practicals']}

print({k: len(v) for k,v in folders.items()})
# {'Master folder': 1, 'Child folder': 4}
```

Comment: correct, but i need to store each item's count into a separate variables. is that possible?

Comment: It's a bad practise to create variable dynamically since it's hard to understand, debug, maintain and introduce security issues. A dictionary answers your question. You might have a look at [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) or [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). [*Some readings why they are bad practise*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

```
folders = {'Master folder': ['Training'], 'Child folder': ['Training videos', 'Training documents', 'Training workouts', 'Training practicals']}

for key in list(folders.keys()):
  print(key, len(folders[key]))

>>>> Master folder 1
>>>>Child folder 4

EDIT: (to store outputs in list)

''''
mylist = []
for key in list(folders.keys()):
  print(key, len(folders[key]))
  mylist.extend(len(folders[key]))
```

Comment: correct ! but I need to store each counts in separate variables

Answer (score 0):

Why need complexity, when you can solve it using only `len` function

```
count_of_masterfolder = len(folders['Master folder'])
count_of_childfolder = len(folders['Child folder'])
```